# How to Remove Square bracket from JSON, PHP or javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

**Requirement :**
how can i convert the following json format.

**From :**

```
[
{"u0":{"user_id":"124", "name":"Eloise R. Morton"}},
{"u1":{"user_id":"126", "name":"Mary S. Williams"}}
]
```

**To :**

```
 {
 "u0":{"user_id":"124", "name":"Eloise R. Morton"},
 "u1":{"user_id":"126", "name":"Mary S. Williams"}
 }
```

I want to delete/remove the first and last square brackets from JSON.

**PHP code :**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user_list";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$user_count=0;
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $user_count_id="u".$user_count;
        $user_count++;
        $user_list[]=   array($user_count_id=>$row);
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
echo json_encode($user_list);
$conn->close();
```

**Javascript code :**

```
function update_user_list(){
    //Fetch data
        $.ajax( "user_list.php" ).done(function(json) {
        user_list       =   json;
        var add_user="";
        for(var obj in user_list){
            add_user +=     '...generate HTML.....';
        }
        $('.user-list-panel .user-table').html(add_user);
        })
    .fail(function() {
        alert( "error" );
    });
```

Comment: `$.getJSON('user_list.php', function(json){` or `$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: "user_list.php",
  data: data,
  success: success
});`

Answer (score 5):

You are adding them yourself when you add values to your array in php:

```
 $user_list[] = array($user_count_id=>$row);
```

If you don't want that, you should use:

```
$user_list[$user_count_id] = $row;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by updating your PHP code.

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $user_count_id="u".$user_count;
        $user_count++;
        $user_list[$user_count_id]=$row;
    }
}
```

// Above script will create single dimensional array with unique keys.

Answer (score 2):

You have to slightly modify your code in order to get the designed structure:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user_list";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$user_count=0;
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $user_count_id="u".$user_count;
        $user_count++;
        $user_list[$user_count_id] = $row;
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
echo json_encode($user_list);
$conn->close();
```

See the line:
 **$user_list[$user_count_id] = $row;**